# Counting how many times a certain object is selected in a multiple drop down box

Tags: javascript, count, counter

I have 7 drop down boxes with "YES" and "NO" answers. They are all on the same page. Along the side of the page, as the user selects yes or no for each answer, I want to have a count that shows how many times they have selected no, and how many times they have selected yes, to update as they fill out the form. So Yes=1, NO= 4, etc. As they select another yes, one is added. If they change their answer to "no", a "yes" is deleted and a  "no" is added to the count.

I am assuming this will be javascript? I am running an asp site so php wont work in this case.

This is used as a reference BEFORE they submit the form, so queries to find out after they submit are useless here.

Comment: Is there any code so far?

Comment: i have gone more specific in this post if you may assist. thank you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283795/counting-how-many-times-a-option-is-selected-in-multiple-drop-down-boxes-with-sa

Answer (score 1):

Yes the solution is easy in JavaScript with jQuery, you supose all the answers by default are yes and start the counter of `yesCounts = 7` and if someone is clicking no you decrement `yesCount--` and increment `noCount++`

```
var yesCount = 7;
var noCount = 0;

$(".no-element").on('click', function () {
    noCount++;
    yesCount--;
});

$(".yes-element").on('click', function () {
    yesCount++;
    noCount--;
});
```

So you should add the class `<options class='yes-element'>Yes</options>` and `<options class='no-element'>No</options>` and make all the default values in options yes

Comment: Note that because the number of answers is fixed you don't really need to count both yes and nos. You just increase and decrease e.g. the number of yes and then you have the no as (7-yes) by another function.

Comment: yep good point you just need to increase `yes`-es and `no` will be `7 - yesCount`

Comment: ok now if the option for other parts are not 'yes' and 'no', but option that are pulled from the database, so the option is   

<option value="<%=vrecordid%>"><%=vrecname%></option>

how could i incorporate the class  "class='yes-element'"  to read class='<%=vrecordid%>'

so then options for the select are pulled from the database and the classes are the record numbers, and the area that is counting the records will have the same record id list, and count how many times the record is selected.

Comment: for example, you have a database of 100 cars. and you have a question, which car is your favorite. which car is good on gas, which car you think is faster.  then the select options are pulled from the database.  on the side will be a list of all 100 cars, with the number next to them of how many times that car was selected in the drop downs.

Comment: you have the `class` element and the `value` element, from database you are getting `<option class="yes-element" value="<%=vrecordid%>"><%=vrecname%></option>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways, one can be javascript and jquery.

```
$("#dropDownId").val();
```

[jquery's doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)